# How to check if SQL Server Agent is running

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, session, session-state

I am using SQL Server 2008 r2. I want to find a way to verify if SQL Server Agent is running. I am suspicious that the Agent isn't running, but I don't know how to check.

Comment: Do you want to check manually? Or from SQL?

Comment: if its possible , i prefer to check from SQL server management studio

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Management Studio, you can check if SQL Server Agent is running by looking at the SQL Server Agent node in Object Explorer. In the following screen shot, SQL Server Agent on my SQL Server 2012 instance is running (green arrow overlaid on the SQL Server Agent icon), but the agent for SQL Server 2000 is stopped (red x).

[image]

You can also check in Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services:

[image]

Or in Program Files > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > Configuration Manager:

[image]

Finally, you can check the state using T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @agent NVARCHAR(512);

SELECT @agent = COALESCE(N'SQLAgent$' + CONVERT(SYSNAME, SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')), 
  N'SQLServerAgent');

EXEC master.dbo.xp_servicecontrol 'QueryState', @agent;
```

Comment: In management studio, instead of the arrows, I see a white circle with green border. What does this mean ? But, in config manager, I see that it is running (green arrow inside white circle).

Comment: In one of the servers, this script caused the error - EXECUTE permission denied on object 'xp_servicecontrol', database 'master', owner 'dbo'.

Comment: @blasto that's not a script problem, that's a permissions problem. Presumably you need to have the right permissions to query the state of a service, no matter what script or UI method you use.

Comment: Yes. Is it advisable to put restricitions on querying - MASTER.dbo.sysprocesses ? Is it a common practice ? If not, then John Sansom's query might be better.

Comment: @blasto I can't possibly answer that question for you - I have no knowledge nor interest in how you want to implement security in your shop. I will tell you that `sysprocesses` has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005, so no, you shouldn't use that answer directly today, unless you want to re-write it later...

Answer (score 17):

The quickest, easiest, most directest way to determine if SQL Agent is running, and that can be done easily in SSMS, is a query (hence it can be automated), *and* isn't querying a deprecated system table (i.e. `sysprocesses`) or EXECing `xp_servicecontrol`, is a DMV that was introduced in SP1 for SQL Server 2008 R2:

[sys.dm_server_services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-server-services-transact-sql)

```sql
SELECT dss.[status], dss.[status_desc]
FROM   sys.dm_server_services dss
WHERE  dss.[servicename] LIKE N'SQL Server Agent (%';
```

Returns:

```
status  status_desc
4       Running
```

It just requires the `VIEW SERVER STATE` server permission, but you already needed that in order to see the status of it in Object Explorer (in SSMS).

AND, if you don't want to grant `VIEW SERVER STATE` to a particular Login because it allows for getting too much other info, then you technically don't need to grant anything at all, at least not to an actual user. See the following two resources for full details (including working examples):

- [What minimum permissions do I need to provide to a user so that it can check the status of SQL Server Agent Service?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103275/30859) (similar question on DBA.StackExchange)
- [Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Server-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/02/15/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-server-level/) (blog post)

Answer (score 11):

If the SQL Server Agent is running, a green play button will be shown in the bottom right corner of the SQL Server Agent icon within SQL Server Management Studio.

To validate the status of the SQL Server Agent for a given instance using T-SQL execute the following code snippet:

```
IF EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
             FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses 
             WHERE program_name = N'SQLAgent - Generic Refresher')
BEGIN
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'InstanceName', 1 AS 'SQLServerAgentRunning'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'InstanceName', 0 AS 'SQLServerAgentRunning'
END
```

Source = [Colin Stasiuk](http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/07/20/check-sql-server-agent-status-on-all-sql-servers/)

Comment: I noticed that you can stop the Agent from management studio. But, after that you cannot restart it from there. You can restart from windows services. I wonder why its like this.

Comment: This worked for me. I saw a '1' for my InstanceName. Works on 2000, 05, 08R2

Comment: ^^^^^sysprocesses has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005, so no, you shouldn't use that answer directly today, unless you want to re-write it later

Answer (score 4):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysprocesses WHERE LEFT(program_name, 8) = 'SQLAgent')
  PRINT 'Agent is running!'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Agent is not connected!';
```

Let me know if this works else try this

```
IF EXISTS (  SELECT 1 

           FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses 

           WHERE program_name = N'SQLAgent - Generic Refresher')

BEGIN

   SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'InstanceName', 1 AS 'SQLServerAgentRunning'

END

ELSE 

BEGIN

   SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'InstanceName', 0 AS 'SQLServerAgentRunning'

END
```

Reference : http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/07/20/check-sql-server-agent-status-on-all-sql-servers/

Comment: Why did you add Colin's code sample to your answer, which was John Samson's answer 7 minutes earlier?

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't checked it.

Comment: But you can remove it, now that you know. There is absolutely no value in having the exact same code sample in two different answers.'

Answer (score 2):

Automate checking if SQL Server Agent is running with this batch file.

It will start start the service if it isn't running already.

You will need to tweak the service name (SQLServerAgent) for some versions of MSSQL.

```
echo off
echo Test SQL Server Agent Service

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "SQLServerAgent" ^| findstr "STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   echo service was stopped, starting service
     rem put your optional errorlog or warning message here
     net start "SQLServerAgent"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in powershell

`Get-Service | Where-Object -like -value '*sql*agent*' -Property 'name'`

Answer (score 0):

Updated in 2020 for Sql Server Developer Addition 2019

View --> Registered Servers --> Local Server Groups

This should list all local servers. If there is a Red X by the server, it's stopped. Or you can right click on it and go to Service Control. From there you can Start/Stop Restart, etc.